# SHow only x posts in wordpress, no matter if sticky posts exist or not

Tags: php, wordpress, sticky, posts

I'm trying to control the post output to three, but Wordpress is adding in Sticky posts which ignore my post limit. So, if I have one sticky post, the page shows 4 posts, not three as it should.

I've searched and found similar issues but the code is so different that I can't make it work in my situation. Full disclosure: I'm not a php expert.

Here's my loop:

```
<?php  query_posts('showposts=3'); ?>
<?php  if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="news-item" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
        <span class="meta-date-group">
            <span class="meta-date-month"><?php the_time('M'); ?></span>
            <span class="meta-date-day"><?php the_time('j'); ?></span>
        </span>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('square'); ?>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
<h4 class="hnews"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>

<div class="hexcerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
<a class="readmore" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >Read More</a>

</div><!--END news-item--> 

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your query argument

```
"post__not_in"   => get_option("sticky_posts")
```

or you can filter your post in loop as:

```
if (!is_sticky())
  {
     // your code
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your query:
`'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1`